# Is there a way to destroy the teapot?

Tags: candy-box-2

Is there any easy way to destroy the teapot or do i just have to wait? I`m currently using my scythe, crown with jaspers and red gloves.

Comment: I did it by just equpping the scythe, red gloves and jasper crown and afking for 15 min. :P

Comment: Remember to remove your knight's armor too, it lowers your DPS

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to destroy the teapot faster than just attacking it regularly and waiting. Even the black hole spell, which kills most enemies, does not do much damage to the teapot. The best strategy is to just make your DPS as high as possible and waiting for your character to kill it.

Answer (score 3):

The teapot has nothing to do with the game; it is just an added a bonus. So beat the game by getting the 4 stones first. This will give you unlimited resources, where you can use pains au chocolat to boost your damage output. I killed the teapot within 4 seconds.

If you try you try to kill it before you beat the game, it will take a considerable amount of time

Comment: I'm not sure this is true - it gives you the spoon, which is the most powerful (if slowest) weapon in the game...

Comment: True, but the scythe is more than enough to beat the game. The spoon really isn't needed to beat any of the levels